# CSS: How to control the render order of borders?

Tags: css

I have a container with some tabs:

```
<div class="tabbed-container">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="active nav-link">Tab 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link">A longer tab name</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link">Last tab</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <p>
      Hey look, some content!
    </p>
    <p>
      More content!
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

.

```
body {
  background-color: white
}

*, *::after, *::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.tabbed-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 2em;
  background-color: white;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.nav-tabs .nav-item {
  margin: 0 3px -1px 3px;
  flex: 1 1 auto
}

.nav-tabs > .nav-item:first-child {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.nav-tabs > .nav-item:last-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.nav-tabs .nav-item a {
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  background-color: #e4e4e4;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-tabs .nav-item a.active,
.nav-tabs .nav-item a:active {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.nav-link {
  display: block;
}

.tab-content {
  padding: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #e4e4e4
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pqmefsbr/34/

I would like for there not to be any border between the content and the active tab. To this end, I've changed the margin on `.nav-tabs .nav-item` from `margin: 0 3px` to `margin: 0 3px -1 3px`, and added `border-bottom: 1px solid white` to the active tab. This doesn't seem to have accomplished anything, though.

After playing around with the border color and thickness to see what is actually going on, it looks like the border of the `content` div is always being rendered on top of the tab's border, so my white `border-bottom` is accomplishing nothing. What can I do to get the tab's border to render on top instead? Is there possibly some other way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: add  `position: relative;` to `.nav` and it's fixed

Comment: Ahhhhhh, thank you so much!
Just one question... why does this work?

Comment: you can read about stacking context and print order ;) initially all your element are static in-flow so they are printed in the order of dom tree. adding relative to the first, i change the order and now the first one is printed later

Comment: @TemaniAfif you should post an answer if you intend to answer the question. Katie: I'd recommend putting your jsfiddle code _into the question itself_ so it helps future readers. If your link or the code in the jsfiddle changes it will cease to be of any use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [**Stacking without the z-index property | MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Stacking_without_z-index)
>
> When the z-index property is not specified on any element, elements
>   are stacked in the following order (from **bottom to top**):
>
> 1. The background and borders of the root element Descendant
> 2. non-positioned blocks, **in order of appearance** in the HTML Descendant
> 3. positioned elements, in order of appearance in the HTML

Short answer is:

```
.nav-tabs {
  position: relative;
  ...
}
```

Related examples:

```css
.a {
  height: 20px;
  background: pink;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}

.b {
  height: 40px;
  border: 10px solid gray;
}

.relative {
  position: relative;
}

.z-index {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<h3>Example 1: all default</h3>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>

<h3>Example 2: 1st position: relative</h3>
<div class="a relative"></div>
<div class="b"></div>

<h3>Example 3: both position: relative</h3>
<div class="a relative"></div>
<div class="b relative"></div>

<h3>Example 4: both position: relative + 1st z-index: 1</h3>
<div class="a relative z-index"></div>
<div class="b relative"></div>
```